# using switch in tablix properties Filters tab

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the following code in my tablix properties in the filters pane,

`=Switch(
Parameters!Year.Value = Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, "Include",
Parameters!Year.Value-1 = Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, "Include",
IIF(Parameters!Year.Value = Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, Fields!Calendar_Year.Value, Fields!Calendar_Year.Value - 2), "Include"
)`

This returns me 3 years of data i.e. 2016, 2015 and 2014. My report is separated by months and as you see I pass a param to the report for the year. See below image:

[image]

So all 3 years show for which i have the data but where I dont have data for 2016 it shows the 2015 and 2014 (which is what I want to see)

I want to know how I can get rid of the 2014 column when there is data for 2016.

Like:(ignore the ordering in the image below)
[image]

EDIT:

[image]
[image]

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[A], [Measures].[B - COUNT], [Measures].[C], [Measures].[D], [Measures].[E], [Measures].[F], [Measures].[G - COUNT],[Measures].[EMAIL], [Measures].[MAIL], [Measures].[RENT] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { ([Order Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS * [Order Date].[Month Number Of Year].[Month Number Of Year].ALLMEMBERS * [Order Date].[Month Name].[Month Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Brand].[Brand Desc].[Brand Desc].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Market].[Market Desc].[Market Desc].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( 
SELECT ( {[Order Date].[Calendar Year].&[2014], [Order Date].[Calendar Year].&[2015], [Order Date].[Calendar Year].&[2016] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Market].[Market Desc].&[UK], [Dim Market].[Market Desc].&[USA] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Order Date].[Month Number Of Year].[All] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Cube]))) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve the desired result by using a `BOTTOM N` operator.

Go to the `Year` column group and right click it, select `Group Properties...`.

[image]

Go to `Filter` tab and set the following settings. If your sorting property is ascending `A-Z` use a `TOP N` operator and value `2`, otherwise descending (Z-A sorting) use `BOTTOM N` operator

[image]

It will filter only the two last years.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: ahh yes that worked. but when i change the Year parameter value to 2015 i expect to see 2015 and 2014 through out but it shows the same result (like the one when i pick 2016 as my year param value)

Comment: If you pick 2016 do you see 2015 and 2014?

Comment: so I have the data up until april so when I pick 2016 as the year param I expected to see 2016 and 2015 (jan-apr) and 2015 and 2014 (may-dec) which works fine. But when I pick 2015 as the year param I expect to see all 2015 and 2014. Basically I am trying to make a rolling 12 months report but I couldn't find anything on it so I took this approach.

Comment: Did you delete the include filter you posted in your question? If you need just two years why are you filtering the selected year and two previous years, in total 3 years?.

Comment: Hey, yes i just deleted the filter as you said. Still the same thing. Any idea why?

Comment: Share a short sample of your data in order to recreate the issue.

Comment: any idea what I can do? Just revisited the issue now @alejandro

Comment: @Faiz, could you share the query that feeds your dataset?

Comment: I updated the question, the query that feeds dataset is there. I hope you can still help. thanks.